# SharePoint 2013, Lookup field cross-Web

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, lookup-column, site-column, sub-site

It looks like I found pretty annoying bug in SharePoint 2013. Can anyone confirm this?

1. Create site-column lookup to list placed on rootWeb (I will refer to it as WebA), the title should be used as lookup value.
2. In WebA create subsite, called WebB, and create there a custom list with site-column lookup (created in point 1).
3. Add new item with any lookup value.
4. Now on listView try to click on lookup link.

Everything works fine, except the last point. It should open viewForm for clicked lookup value, but it shows 'List not found error'. Link generated by SharePoint build-in lookupField is scoped to current Web, not to root Web. This works fine in SharePoint 2010 (correct scope).

Have anyone came across this bug? Any idea of solving it, without writing dirty JS code?

Example:

result:
`http://sharepoint/somesubsite1/someSubSite2/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={b2ed78a9-117b-4302-93de-2a4dbfade5d3}&ID=1&RootFolder=*`

expected result:
`http://sharepoint/_layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId={b2ed78a9-117b-4302-93de-2a4dbfade5d3}&ID=1&RootFolder=*`

Seems like this bug was patched in some CU. I need more time to confirm this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine in April 2013 update.